# Override a model's DELETE method from real delete to setting a property in Django RESTful framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

We are using a django-rest-framework as our backend. I have a model Product which is the Foreign Key of another Order model, which acts as both a order and an audit log.

Now suppose we are not going to sell this Product anymore. We need to apply DELETE method on the Product; and we still want to preserve everything in Order. **However, if the Product is really deleted and the on_delete method on it is SET_NULL, then all info that is related to Product is lost.** Which is not what I wanted.

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

So my question is:

1. A common practice in other framework is using soft-delete, i.e. adding a "delete=0" property on Product. And the DELETE method only change the property to "delete=1" rather than real delete. Is it do-able when using django-rest-framework? And how?
2. Is there any other good practices to realize this requirement, i.e. to delete the foreign key while perserving the foreign key's metadata?

Answer (score 1):

You can add one timestamp field in your Product model.

For example.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,  null=True)
```

Now while deleting the product:

For example if you are using ModelViewset

```
from django.utils import timezone

class ProductViewset(ModelViewSet):
  .......
  def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      product = self.get_object()
      product.deleted_at = timezone.now()
      product.save()
      return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Now you have to query your all product objects with

```
Product.objects.filter(deleted_at=None)
```

instead of

```
Product.objects.all()
```